# Qt: Bad window icon quality

Tags: c++, windows, image, qt, window

I'm using Qt 5.10.1. I created a window icon resource and applied to Qt application like following:

```
a.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/icons/resources/logo_icon.png"));
```

The size of `logo_icon.png` is 256*256.

The result is this:

[image: window icon image]

The icon is a little blurrly, which is not what I expected. For comparison, following is the window icon of GIMP in which I designed the icon:

[image: gimp window icon image]

I tried various sizes of the image from 16*16 to 256*256, there was no luck. Changing image format to ico from png also didn't work.

What should I do to render a clearer window icon?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the ui file of your window there is a `iconSize` value that makes your icon scale not very well when rendered by the window manager. This blurry effect occurred to me sometimes because the size was 15 px instead of 16 (or another power of 2).

Try to open the .ui file of your main window in Design mode and look under the **QMainWindow** group in the widget properties panel to set the `iconSize` to something like 16.

You can also set the icon file from there, using the `windowIcon` property under the **QWidget** group.

Comment: `iconSize` value already had been set 16x16, and adjusting it to something like 32x32, 256x256 didn't took the blurry effect away. However, thank you for the answer & information!

Comment: Maybe, given the kind of image, you could try to use the svg format. I never tested, but it may result in better scaling from the qt icon engine side. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try!